# What are the best ways to connect two coordinates on mapinfo?

Tags: cartography, mapinfo, mapbasic

I have with the help of this forum drawn a coordinate system with longitude and latitude at different location. I am trying to connect these sites what is the best way to connect. Is it just drawing lines or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL+S to turn snap on, make the layer editable (right click>Layer Control and check the middle check box), then click on the first point (a cross hair will show) and drag a line to the othe rpoint (where another cross hair will show), then release the mouse.

You will have a line

If you want the line created in its own layer, when you open layer control, make the cosmetic layer editable, perofmr the operation, then save cosmetic objects as a new layer.

Comment: @ Hairy the answer I wanted :) thanks Actually it's not check box but it's some edit button in mapinfo professinal 10.5

Comment: What is the difference between two layers for joining two points.

Comment: When you say joining two points, do you mean creating a line, or combining the two points into one object?

Effectively, in MapInfo, you'll do most editing on one layer.  If you want to use two layers, do the work in the cosmetic layer and save the objects created in that layer, to your own new layer, or make one of the layers editable and copy new data into that layer.

Comment: I wanted to join two points.

Comment: into one object?

Comment: if so, make the layer they are in editable, and select one point by clicking on it, then select the other while holding down the ctrl key, then go into the object menu and select 'combine objects', this will then combie to the two objects; they will look like two points, but will act as one.

Answer (score 4):

If you only have to do it once and there is only two points I would just do it by hand, else you can use a tool called ConnectTheDots.MBX which can be found here: http://www.mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=10&sobi2Id=35&Itemid=53